# Softlink for a file on a remote machine

Tags: filesystem

I want to create a softlink for a file between two servers. The file is present on a server 1 and a softlink should be created for it on server2.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use NFS and mount the folder with the file on server1 on server2 as a client.

Comment: Exactly. Or Samba or [SSHFS](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) or AFS or whatever is needed to access the other server.